# What is an efficient way to split keys and values into separate objects?

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js

I have an object that is a series of keys and values.

```
 var dataset =
    {"diamonds":77,
     "gold-bars":28,
     "exciting-stuff":52,
     "oil":51,
     "sports-cars":7,
     "bitcoins":40};
```

I want to split each key value into it's own object in an array, so it would look like.

```
var dataset =
    [{"asset":"diamonds", "quantity":77},
      {"asset":"gold-bars", "quantity":28},
      {"asset":"exciting-stuff", "quantity":52},
      {"asset":"oil", "quantity":51},
      {"asset":"bitcoins", "quantity":40},]
```

I have been using underscore, but I'm not sure what this type of conversion would be be called. 
Is there a good pattern for it? Or is what I'm doing non standard?

Comment: Why not a simple `for..in` loop with an `Array.push`? Super trivial, no libraries needed.

Comment: used a bench mark tool for all the answerers here http://jsperf.com/map-pairs  Object.keys() and Array.prototype.map() is fractionally faster then for ... in. but Object.keys()  does not work in legacy browsers such as IE 8. none the less it is the fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this purpose.

```js
var dataset = { "diamonds": 77, "gold-bars": 28, "exciting-stuff": 52, "oil": 51, "sports-cars": 7, "bitcoins": 40 },
    result = Object.keys(dataset).map(function (k) { 
        return { asset: k, quantity: dataset[k] };
    });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate through object.
>
> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

```js
var obj = {
  "diamonds": 77,
  "gold-bars": 28,
  "exciting-stuff": 52,
  "oil": 51,
  "sports-cars": 7,
  "bitcoins": 40
};
var finalArr = [];
for (var i in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    var myObj = {};
    myObj['asset'] = i;
    myObj['uantity'] = obj[i];
    finalArr.push(myObj);
  }
}
console.log(finalArr);
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/38e5f6f8/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Underscore, you could do:

```
_.map(_.pairs(dataset), _.partial(_.object, ['asset', 'quantity']))
```

`_.pairs` converts your objects into arrays of `[key, value]` pairs, which are then mapped into objects with the `asset` and `quantity` properties.